# How can I draw following pictures?

Tags: surfaces, math-software

I need to draw simple surface. For example, how can I draw following pictures? Can I draw them online?

[image]

Comment: You might look at sites like geogebra.org although that's a bit more structured. Are you looking for a free online whiteboard? If so, there are a lot of them, though nothing really spectacular (Google docs and wiziq.com are my favorites)

Comment: Perhaps try [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com). There are packages to do that, such as psscripts or tikz

Comment: TikZ is commonly recommended for something like this. And similarly, when I've been unable to use TikZ, I just try making diagrams in Inkscape (Adobe Illustrator would be the proprietary alternative).

Comment: Inkscape is what you are looking for.